# error: C2057: expected constant expression

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, compiler-errors, qt-creator

I'm trying to build a project orignally made on top of mingw but now we need to switch to MSVC++ (because a specific debugging library only supports that) but to my surprise, compiling that code even on new C++ version/Qt result in the error:

> error: C2057: expected constant expression

The error is not part of my own source code rather Qt itself, from `qmetatype.h` header, so I have no idea how fix. I assumed it was missing C++11 flag, so I added `CONFIG += c++11` nothing changed. Then I tried to more specific and added `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /std:c++14` to `.pro` file. Same error. The line of error is:

```
struct CapabilitiesImpl<T, std::random_access_iterator_tag>
{ enum { IteratorCapabilities = RandomAccessCapability | BiDirectionalCapability | ForwardCapability }; };
```

NOTE: Since I was getting cl not found error, I do star the Qt creator from a **qt.bat** file like this:

```
call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
Studio\2017\Community\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86
"C:\Qt-MSVC\Qt5.7.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\qtcreator.exe"
```

How can I fix that?

**UPDATE**

I've tried to use an older version to see if it makes any differentce, which didn't but I got more context about the error:

> C:\Qt-MSVC\Qt5.5.0\5.5\msvc2013\include\QtCore\qmetatype.h:944: see
>   reference to class template instantiation
>   'QtMetaTypePrivate::CapabilitiesImpl,std::random_access_iterator_tag>'
>   being compiled
>   C:\Qt-MSVC\Qt5.5.0\5.5\msvc2013\include\QtCore\qmetatype.h:1015: see
>   reference to class template instantiation
>   'QtMetaTypePrivate::ContainerAPI' being compiled with [
>       T=QVariantList ] C:\Qt-MSVC\Qt5.5.0\5.5\msvc2013\include\QtCore\qvariant.h:711: see
>   reference to function template instantiation
>   'QtMetaTypePrivate::QSequentialIterableImpl::QSequentialIterableImpl(const
>   T *)' being compiled with [
>       T=QVariantList ]

Comment: We can't know if you don't include definitions for the enum values. My feeling is that you are not linking the files properly, therefore the linker can not find the definition for the values you are using in the `enum`.

Comment: How can I make sure it's done? as I said, that header file is part of Qt source code itself not my own

Comment: Link the Qt libraries with your project

Comment: What errors do you get after when you run the project after you have run the vcvarsall.bat?

Comment: @MivVG: Newly created applications does work, the issue is only with that Project...

Comment: @nikaltipar After the successfull environment initiliazation for x86 by vcvarsall.bat I run the Qt creator which result in the error in the question when compiling. The previous error was `cl` command not found.

Answer (score 0):

You do need to define the *MSVC*-specific environment variables when you are make something in QT using the *MSVC* compiler. Therefore, running `vcvarsall.bat` is mandatory, unless you manually define those environment variables yourself.

> VCVarsall.bat is Visual Studio Command Prompt tool in Visual Studio. It's the tool that allows you to set various options for the integrated development environment (IDE) as well as build, debug, and deploy projects from the command line.
>
> [Source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ca6b8797-7384-4584-8dd2-27ae2663ed02/what-vcvarsallbat-does?forum=vssetup)

Comment: I run that before I start Qt creator (check my bat script in question) is not that enough or should I add it to say, Build steps?

Comment: It is enough. Does that error arise after you run vcvarsall?

Comment: I've just tried adding as build step before read you 2 comment, it didn't change the error anyway

Comment: check out the update, if it helps to trace the error reason

Comment: cl is this compiler: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.12.25827\bin\Hostx86\x86\cl.exe` is this the correct one, meant to be used with Qt 5.7.1?